# How do I know if I get a remainder in some intermediate steps when evaluating eval() in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string, something like `(4*1+3)/2`, and want to use `eval` to evaluate the answer. How could I know if I will get a remainder in some intermediate step? In this case, I get a remainder in the last step, where I will evaluate 7/2.

Assume all arguments are integers, and the only allowed operands are +, -, *, /, (, ).

Comment: Please, please, do not use `eval`! It will execute anything it's thrown, including harmful statements. Write your own parser or find a library.

Comment: I'm new to Python. What are some potential risks of using eval? I use eval since it looks convenient and clean to use.

Comment: Suppose you use this function on a web server: you let the user enter expressions and then you send back the result. What if the user enters `print open('/path/to/the/file/with/passwords').read()` or even `import shutils; shutils.rmtree('/')`? You should always sanitize input. `eval` is more a debug/kludge function than something you would use in programs.

Comment: You could try looking into the `divmod` function. It will return a tuple containing the quotient and the remainder. Perhaps create a function `divide(x, y): q, r = divmod(x, y); if y: raise Exception else: return` and replace all `/` with `divide`, or something of that nature.

Answer (score 1):

If you do

```
from __future__ import division
```

you will get the new, Python 3-style division:

```
>>> eval("(4*1+3)/2")
3.5
```

and you'll know that you got a remainder somewhere because the output is of type `float`.

Comment: So besides checking whether the value has fractional parts, there is no cleaner ways to do so? If the numbers get bigger, there could be precision errors.

Comment: @chhung6: there's surely a clean way, but not an easy one. defuz's answer would be the start of a clean solution but you'll have to do the evaluation yourself.

Comment: Btw, it seems that it won't catch this case: eval("1/2*2"）

Comment: @chhung6 Actually, `1 / 2 * 2` evaluates to `1.0`, of type `float`, rather than `1`, of type `int`. (Try it!) So @larsmans's approach still works here. (This is because this parses as `(1 / 2) * 2`, which evaluates to `0.5 * 2`, which evals to `1.0`.)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`ast.parse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.parse) function:

```
>>> import ast
>>> x = ast.parse('(4*1+3)/2', mode='eval')
>>> x.body.left
<_ast.BinOp object at 0x100613210>
>>> x.body.right
<_ast.Num object at 0x100613590>
>>> x.body.op
<_ast.Div object at 0x10060d2d0>
```

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works for you, you may try some custom code to **evaluate infix expression**. See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429712/evaluating-an-infix-expression-python) for using stack to evaluate infix expression. Or check out some code on this [blog](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/03/20/a-recursive-descent-parser-with-an-infix-expression-evaluator/).

It seems that there is no library or module or component to help you with what you want to do. You might have to write your own.